# Threads and template member functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I got a template member function that I call using .template :

```
myObject.template memberFunction<someArguments...>(); //not variadic (but template of template)
```

I wanted to thread this call with std::thread. So I tried this :

```
std::thread myThread(&myClass::memberFunction<someArguments...>, &myObject);
```

But this doesn't compile. It seems this is a parsing problem since it 'expected primary-expression before' the parenthesis and the comma.

ps : I am french and new to c++ so I just hope this is understandable.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to write more detailed questions.

Comment: Give us a complete, minimal example.

Comment: (really fast :o) Ok. I will. Thank you.

Comment: Well my minimal example works.

Comment: @matovitch I've already provided a minimal example with my answer. Follow the link.

Comment: Also, the chorus of question critics aren't the police here… and the requests to make the question easier aren't always warranted or productive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `template` keyword after `::`, the same as it was after `.`. Yes, the same parser issue applies.

[Quick demo here.](http://ideone.com/FazTRe)